# HTML/Javascript collapse columns using the row header

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to get a number of columns to collapse/hide when clicking the col-span above them, leaving only the "Total" column. All the date columns need to be hidden when clicking the "AUD - API Sandbox213" area. All I currently have is the following, not even sure if Im headed in the right direction.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.collapseColumn').click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .parent()
      .next('thead')
      .toggleClass('collapsedColumn');
  });
});
```

```css
.collapsedColumn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th colspan="dynamic to the number of months displayed"class="collapseColumn"</th>
<th></th>
<th colspan="1"></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Month</th>  // multiplied by the number of months displayed
<th>Spacer</th> // multiplied by the number of months displayed
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Month Value</th> // multiplied by the number of months displayed
<th>Spacer</th>      // multiplied by the number of months displayed
<th>Total</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

All the code does is hide the dates only, I need the values to hide as well, leaving only the "Total" column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the HTML code of the table without PHP

Comment: @Patrik - I have tried to clean the code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code of the problem you have tried to solve:
http://jsfiddle.net/ruz4vobe/15/

I hope I understood your problem well and this is what you tried to achieve...

**I made an example just to show you the way you should think about the problem. Your approach is not good.**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="7" class="collapseColumn">AUD - API Sandbox 123</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="toHide">Jul'18</th>
      <th class="toHide">Jul'18</th>
      <th class="toHide">Jul'18</th>
      <th class="toHide">Jul'18</th>
      <th class="toHide">Jul'18</th>
      <th class="toHide">Jul'18</th>
      <th class="total">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="toHide">0</td>
      <td class="toHide">1</td>
      <td class="toHide">2</td>
      <td class="toHide">3</td>
      <td class="toHide">4</td>
      <td class="toHide">5</td>
      <td class="total">15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

First of all somehow you have to specify those fields you want to hide. You can do it with classes, or data-attributes in HTML5 or however you want, even with CSS if the `last-child()` of the `tr` always will be the your **total**

```
$('body').on('click', '.collapseColumn', function(e){
  $.each($(".toHide"), function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

When you click on your `.collapseColumn` field that should trigger an event, where you check all of the fields which you want to try to modify. If a field's value/data-content/class etc doesn't match your requirements, you can simply just hide it with a class, which you toggle when you are clicking on your `.collapseColumn`.

Comment: Thank you Patrik, it is what I am looking to do, I just need to translate this to my code now. Thank you again !

Comment: No problem, it's just a basic example for the problem, I didn't specify it, so if you have any problem to implement it into your code, just write it here :)